# pq.NewListener/Listen blocks with pq: syntax error at or near "listen"

Tags: cockroachdb, pq

I have minio/s3 object store with lambda notifications into cockroachdb (postgres db). I am trying to monitor these events with below golang code.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
    "time"
)

const (
    //crdbConnectStr = "dbname=alerts user=crdbuser1 host=localhost port=26257 sslmode=disable connect_timeout=5"
    crdbConnectStr = "postgres://crdbuser1@localhost:26257/alerts?sslmode=disable"
    dbDriver       = "postgres"
)

func monitorEvents() {

    _, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, crdbConnectStr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("connection open to crdb failed - %v\n", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("sql open on crdb OK\n")

    reportProblem := func(ev pq.ListenerEventType, err error) {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("NewListener - event : %v, err - %v\n", ev, err.Error())
        }
    }

    minReconnect := 2 * time.Second
    maxReconnect := 20 * time.Second
    listener := pq.NewListener(crdbConnectStr, minReconnect, maxReconnect, reportProblem)
    err = listener.Listen("monitor")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Listen error - %v\n", err.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("begin monitoring events in CRDB\n")

    for {
        waitForAlertEvents(listener)
    }
}

// Record holds json data from object.
type Record struct {
    Data struct {
        Value struct {
            Records []struct {
                S3 struct {
                    Bucket struct {
                        Name string `json:"name"`
                    } `json:"bucket"`
                    Object struct {
                        Key string `json:"key"`
                    } `json:"object"`
                } `json:"s3"`
            } `json:"Records"`
        } `json:"value"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

func waitForAlertEvents(l *pq.Listener) {

    for {
        select {
        case n := <-l.Notify:
            fmt.Printf("Received data from channel [%v]\n", n.Channel)
            // Prepare notification payload for pretty print
            fmt.Println(n.Extra)
            record := Record{}

            jerr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(n.Extra), &record)
            if jerr != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error processing JSON: ", jerr)
                return
            }

            bucket := record.Data.Value.Records[0].S3.Bucket.Name
            object := record.Data.Value.Records[0].S3.Object.Key
            fmt.Printf("received event on bucket: %v, object: %v\n", bucket, object)

            return

        case <-time.After(60 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println("Received no events for 90 seconds, checking connection")
            go func() {
                l.Ping()
            }()
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    monitorAlerts()
}
```

When I run this program, I see the below errors and it stucks.

```
[root]# ./alerts 
sql open on crdb OK
NewListener - event : 3, err - pq: syntax error at or near "listen"
NewListener - event : 3, err - pq: syntax error at or near "listen"
NewListener - event : 3, err - pq: syntax error at or near "listen"
```

Connection to cockroachdb manually works OK.

```
[root]# cockroach sql --insecure --user=crdbuser1

crdbuser1@:26257/defaultdb> show databases;                                                                                                               database_name  
+---------------+
  alerts         
(1 row)

Time: 1.22359ms

crdbuser1@:26257/defaultdb> set database=alerts;
SET

Time: 363.994µs

crdbuser1@:26257/alerts> show tables;
  table_name  
+------------+
  alertstab   
(1 row)

Time: 1.399014ms

crdbuser1@:26257/alerts>
```

Any thoughts as why the error `pq: syntax error at or near "listen"`. Also I was looking at
pq sources, the error most likely related to [notify.go#L756](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/d7918e36bee0ef49ef3dd9a17e575de83b26aac6/notify.go#L756)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that CockroachDB does not support the [`LISTEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-listen.html) and [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) statements.

You will need to find a different way of doing this. The closest thing in CRDB would be [Change Data Capture](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v19.2/change-data-capture.html#main-content), but that is more about data streaming than custom notifications.

You can find some discussion about `LISTEN` / `NOTIFY` for CRDB in [this issue](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/41522), but there is no firm plan to date.